# How to stop loop with delay to continue another

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make two things happen at once, but only one of them is allowed. If something is already occuring, I need to be able to stop that completely and let the other one take over. Here is my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/mortenmoulder/5eceLvgu/

```
function log(text, interval, amount) {
    (function myLoop(i) {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(text);
            if (--i) myLoop(i);
        }, interval)
    })(amount);
}

$("#first").on("click", () => log("first", 500, 10));
$("#second").on("click", () => log("second", 500, 10));
```

Click on the first button, it will `console.log("first")` 10 times with a 500ms delay. When you click on the second button, it should cancel the first one and start `console.log("second")` without being interrupted (unless you click on the first button).

How can I do that? I need to delay the loop and I need to have one function to do this (so not a lot of if-statements with each button, as there are many buttons).

Comment: Maybe [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the timer id and clear it if you call `log`:

```
var logTimer;

function log(text, interval, amount) {
  clearTimeout(logTimer);
  (function myLoop(i) {
    logTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(text);
      if (--i) myLoop(i);
    }, interval)
  })(amount);
}
```

Comment: Huh, that's really weird. I did that before and it didn't work. Apologies.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaah I accidentally wrote clearInterval instead. Dammit.

Answer (score 0):

You are already storing the timer, so you can clear its timeout.

https://jsfiddle.net/5eceLvgu/1/

```
var timer;
function log(...)
    clearTimeout(timer);
    (function myLoop(i) {
```